# Remainder of $2^{100} (\mod\ 89)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble coming to the answer on this question:

**Find the remainder when $2^{100}$ is divided by $89$. (Hint: Simplify $2^{10} \pmod{89}$ first.)**

So I went with the hint and found $2^{10} = 45 \pmod{89}$, but I don't think I would want to follow that logic to ${2^{10}}^{10} = 45^{10} \pmod{89}$ and that's all I can think to do. All of the problems I've come across so far have been more straightforward, as far as simplifying to find a remainder with $\pm1$ and then playing with the equation from there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since $2^{10}\equiv 45$ then $2^{11} \equiv 90 \equiv 1$

Comment: **Hint:** $45\times 2=1 \pmod{89}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use little Fermat or the repeated squaring algorithm to compute
$$
2^{100}\equiv 2\bmod 89.
$$
We have $2^{89}\equiv 2\bmod 89$ and $2^{11}\equiv 1\bmod 89$. Then multiply these congruences.

Comment: Well, this seems painfully obvious now. Thank you so much! I really have trouble seeing these things sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

Since $89$ is a prime number,

$$2^{89} \equiv 2 \pmod{89}$$

by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Now you only need to multiply in the remainder of $2^{11} = 2^{10}\cdot 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $89$ is a prime so $2^{88}\equiv1\pmod {89}$ also (by brute force) $2^{12}\equiv2\pmod {89}$

So $2^{100}\equiv 2^{12}\equiv 2 \pmod{89}$